# Id is not defined in adding item to cart

Tags: reactjs, duplicates

I'm trying to make the function add to cart but it's not working, i got the error as "**cart is not defined**" as i click on the button "add to cart". Is there anything wrong with my codes, please help me! Thank you so much!

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Products from "./components/Products";

export default function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Products cart={cart} setCart={setCart} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Products.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { products } from "../data";

function Products() {
  const addToCart = (id) => {
    console.log("in cart");
    let newCart = [...cart];
    let itemInCart = newCart.find((item) => item.id === id);
    if (itemInCart) {
      itemInCart.quantity++;
    }
    newCart.push(itemInCart);

    setCart(newCart);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {products.map((product) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <img src={product.img} />
            <div className="product-info">
              <h3>{product.title}</h3>
              <span>{product.price}$</span>
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => addToCart(product.id)}>Add to cart</button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Products;
```

Sandbox link for better observation: https://codesandbox.io/s/cart-vjhfb?file=/src/components/Products.js

Answer (score 0):

You should get it from props

```
function Products(props) {

    let newCart = [...props.cart];
}
```

Comment: well, i tried but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you forgot to define props in Product.js!

```
// Product.js
function Products ({ cart , setCart }){
 .........
}
```

Comment: well, i tried but it's not working...